# How to change the Progress dialogue bar Color and background

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I tried to display progress dialog and got it but now want to know how to set background color for Progress dialogue and have to set color for Progress Bar. Any help Appreciated
My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog progress;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progress= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progress.setMessage("Loading...!");
            progress.show();

        }
    });

}}
```

XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:text="Start"/>
```

Comment: There are lot! What have you tried before? For sample, take a look at [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+change+color+of+progressdialg&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#hl=en&q=android+change+color+of+progress+dialog&spell=1&sa=X&ei=W18sUd-_K4esrAfUyYHoBA&ved=0CDAQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42965579,d.bmk&fp=65d5127db86895ca&biw=1600&bih=711)

Comment: @Praveen i have create XML file in drawable and set background in XML layout .